# Is there any way to reduce xquartz loading time on osx?

Tags: x11, osx

I'm working under osx environment. Whenever I run some program which need to use xquartz(x11), ghostscript or gnuplot with x11 terminal, I have to wait about 10 seconds to launch Xquartz. It's NOT a terminallike. Is there any way to reduce xquartz loading time on osx?